# How does the addThis facebook like button work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, addthis

Can anyone please explain how the addThis facebook like button works?
The code for adding the button is

`<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>`

I'm going through the code of a website with pages listing details of different products. There is this fb like button on each of those pages. What exactly is **liked** here? Since I don't provide any facebook URL which specifies the page or image or anything related to this product that I've already put on facebook, what is this like button liking?

Comment: It is liking the web page that you put this button on ...

Comment: Liking the web page? How? Where are these likes stored? Does it mean then it is not an actual facebook like? How is facebook involved?

Comment: Facebook considers _all_ external URLs "Open Graph Objects", and they can be liked.